# Find out if account is disabled using terminal

Tags: catalina

I need to find out if account is disabled using terminal on Catalina but without using pwpolicy. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work.

```
dseditgroup -o checkmember -u testuser com.apple.access_disabled
```

Source: https://www.jamf.com/jamf-nation/discussions/14825/ea-for-disabled-accounts